# Is there a keyboard shortcut to load images on a webpage using Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, images

I'm on holiday abroad, and the hotel we're living at has wireless internet so I can check my email and the local news. It is rather slow though, so I've ticked off the checkbox 'Load images automatically' in Mozilla Firefox, which works great. However, occationally I want to turn on images for some articles. Is there a keyboard  shortcut I can use to turn on images on the webpage I'm at? Is there any other browser where this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image-Show-Hide](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-show-hide/) looks as though it does what you want.